# JSON + DB, рационально ли?

Tags: mysql, json

Рационально ли хранить JSON в базе данных (в моем случае MySQL)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нет, и это из разряда аксиом.

- Если это джейсон регулярной структуры, то надо спроектировать под неё структуру таблиц, и записывать данные в неё.
- Если это джейсон нерегулярной структуры, то его надо хранить в предназначенном для него хранилище - которое обеспечит доступ и индексацию индивидуальных полей. Например Монго.

Однако следует понимать, что реляционные БД служат человечеству верой и правдой уже пол-века и - что характерно - несмотря на nosql истерию, не собираются сдавать свои позиции. Поэтому любые идеи на поиграться с джейсон-хранилищем надо себе прозволять только после изучения принципов реляционных БД. Которые и за целостностью данных следят, и строгую структуру имеют, и позволяют работать с данными любых объемов.

Comment: sql не исключает json http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-json.html